# Reorder Entity Properties

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, dynamic-data

I have an Entity (Extensions) with a number of properties (e.g. id, extension, prefix) and a few navigation properties (phones_departments, phones_buildings) - they show up in the order they display in the EDMX...but what if I want them to display in a different order? I'm using Dynamic Data - is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you showing your data in a grid?

if yes, you could sort grid columns based on some other property. You could for example have a ColumnOrder property in your data store and update that. The code to sort the columns varies per grid, but it is usually easy to do.

Main point being is that you want to modify the display level logic, not the way the actual object is created. since your order can always very per application.